# Show diff between files in current version and version with sha1 a971e9d51b8b5adbf387ed04c44459cd30b27

Tags: git

How to see difference in file Default.java between current version and version with sha1 
a971e9d51b8b5adbf387ed04c44459cd30b27 ? I am using git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git diff HEAD a971e9d51b8b5adbf387ed04c44459cd30b27 -- Default.java
```